# Microsoft Teams list display of participations

Tags: microsoft-teams

need help with Microsoft Teams. I want to list all the conversations I  have participated in a channel. I not interested in mentions. Is it possible?

Comment: Is it related to programming or just the question related to Microsoft teams ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the chanel conversation using [/messages](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_list_messages) Graph APIs programmatically.